# Canadian Citizen with Irish passport and summer job in UK - where to pay taxes?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, taxes, ireland

My son has an 8 week summer job in the UK. He is Canadian but holds an Irish passport as well (due to grandparent's being Irish). I understand he can work in the UK without a visa due to his Irish passport. Should he arrive in the UK on his Irish passport to ensure he can work without a visa?

In addition, he will be paying his Canadian taxes as he is domiciled in Canada. I assume he should declare himself non domiciled in the UK? I assume all his tax source deductions will be credited as foreign tax paid on his Canadian tax return?

Comment: He has no choice but to arrive on his Irish passport if he wants to work. He’ll also have to show it to his employer to prove his right to work.

Comment: "Should he arrive in the UK on his Irish passport to ensure he can work without a visa?" No, he can work without a visa because he's an Irish citizen.  He should use his Irish passport to enter the UK because he won't be able to enter the UK for the purpose of working using his Canadian passport without a work visa.

Comment: [For income tax some relevant information is here](https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad/personal-allowance). Assuming his UK income is less than the personal allowance he should pay no income tax in the UK, though he may need to file form R43 to recover any that is withheld. He'll be taxed on that income (or not) on his Canadian return.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and input. I sincerely appreciate it.